# Editable column in a table using jQuery and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a static table and would like to update the data. This is an example of what I want to implement: http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/63/

I tried exactly the same scripts but it still doesn't work.

These are the scripts that I have imported:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitterbootstrap/2.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://vitalets.github.com/x-editable/assets/x-editable/bootstrap-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://vitalets.github.com/x-editable/assets/mockjax/jquery.mockjax.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitterbootstrap/2.2.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://vitalets.github.com/x-editable/assets/x-editable/bootstrap-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css">
```

This is the Javascript:

```
$('#users a').editable({
    type: 'text',
    name: 'username',
    url: '/post',
    title: 'Enter username'
});

//ajax emulation
$.mockjax({
    url: '/post',
    responseTime: 200
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<p>X-editable: create editable column in table.<br>
 As pk is unique in each row, you should put it in data-pk attribute.  
</p>
<div style="margin: 150px">
    <table id="users" class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
        <tr><th>#</th><th>name</th><th>age</th></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><a href="#" data-pk="1">Mike</a></td>
            <td>21</td>       
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td><a href="#" data-pk="2">John</a></td>
            <td>28</td>       
        </tr>        

        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td><a href="#" data-pk="3">Mary</a></td>
            <td>24</td>       
        </tr>        

    </table>    
</div>
```

Tried with the same codes but does not display how jsfiddle does it! Any help on this please?

Comment: Do you get any javascript errors?

Comment: Is problem with //netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitterbootstrap/2.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js ? It return 404 Not found.
Try change to //netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.

GEMI - There doesn't seem to have any javascript errors.

kubedan - I have changed, but still does not display like jsfiddle did.

Comment: Your code doesn't work or doesn't look like jsfiddle? (Problem with css files)
Looks like it as http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/1244/ ?

Comment: Try change URL `//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js` to `http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js`

Comment: My code doesn't work. when I click on the name, for example Mike, it just doesn't respond anywhere. not sure what has not been imported as well. Changed the URL but still getting the same response.

Comment: I try on my localhost and it works. [Try it](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6w7tl7j5re7alel/testjs.html)